# How create Authenticate user during Splash Screen in Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

```
class SplashScreenActivity:AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity)

        Handler().postDelayed({
            FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { auth ->
                val user = auth.currentUser
                if(user != null) {
                    startProfileActivity()
                    print("Hello")
                } else {
                    startLoginActivity()
                    print("Hell")
                }
            }
            finish()
        },1500)


    }

    private fun startLoginActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun startProfileActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

**My question**

I try to create a splash screen that can authenticate whether the user is already login or not by using firebase. However, my current code produces the splash screen that waits for 1500 micro sec and the app is close. Can anyone guide me through this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use finish like this:

```
private fun startLoginActivity() {
    val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}

private fun startProfileActivity() {
    val intent = Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}
```

Because finish() line seems to be running before AuthStateListener is complete. For this reason, the application closes.

```
Handler().postDelayed({
        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        if(user != null) {
             startProfileActivity()
                print("Hello")
        } else {
             startLoginActivity()
             print("Hell")
        }
},1500)
```

**FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener**
*This method gets invoked in the UI thread on changes in the authentication state:*

> Right after the listener has been registered
>
> When a user is signed in
>
> When the current user is signed out
>
> When the current user changes

Comment: Sir, after I change the finish() into startLoginActivity() and startProfileActivity(). However, It does not result in authentication correctly and changes to the next activity. what I get is that the app is freezing on the splash screen.

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer. You can check user state this way.